# Runtime Optimization of sympy code using numpy or scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sympy

I'm new to programming and it's my first question here. I spend a lot of time on this problem. It's an abstract from a programme I'm writing for my thesis. Maybe it's trivial to some of you experts but I might even lack mathematical knowledge.

I want to solve following set of equations for b1, b2 and c3:

```
0 = cos(b1)+ cos(b2)- 0.0166
0 = sin(b1)+ sin(b2)+ 0.3077*c3 - 0.6278
0 = cos(b1)- cos(b2)+ 5.4155*c3 - 4.3547
```

b1 and b2 are angles and should therefore between [0, 2*pi] and c3 should be between [0,1], but this is not necessary. I can filter results later.

I found a solution using sympy:

```
import sympy as sy
b1 = sy.Symbol('b1',real=True)
b2 = sy.Symbol('b2',real=True)
c3 = sy.Symbol('c3',real=True)
a = sy.cos(b1)+sy.cos(b2)-0.0166
b = sy.sin(b1)+sy.sin(b2)+0.3077*c3-0.6278
c = sy.cos(b1)-sy.cos(b2)+5.4155*c3-4.3547
Erg = sy.solve([a,b,c,],[b1,b2,c3],dict=True)
```

[{c3: -0.4634, b1: 2.7245, b2: 0.3739}]

The results are reasonable, but unfortunately this leads to a calculation time of 6s which would result in a total calculation time of over 7hrs for my programme. Please help me find a faster solution. I tried scipy

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def equations(p):
    b1, b2, c3 = p
    return (np.cos(b1)+np.cos(b2)-0.0166, np.sin(b1)+np.sin(b2)+0.3077*c3-0.6278,np.cos(b1)-np.cos(b2)+5.4155*c3-4.3547)

b1, b2, c3 =  fsolve(equations, (-0.4634, 2.7245, 0.3739))
```

This results in under 1s in (-9.8418e-14, 5.6621e-15,-7.5495e-14). I don't know which number belongs to which variable, but they don't make any sense anyway. Another option would be optimizing the equation for minimal c3. Please don't hesitate to ask if I haven't been clear about anything.

Comment: The `numpy` case can only know the order of variables from the function definition: you pass `p` as `b1,b2,c3`. But then you must input your data in this order: `fsolve(equations, (2.7245, 0.3739,-0.4634))`. But anyway you're right that `(0,0,0)` does not solve your equation. Aren't you missing a parenthesis in your `numpy` `return`, though?

Comment: Yeah you're right it got lost while changing the question, but it's there in the original code. Thanks for the comment on correct order of variables!

Comment: Interestingly, if I try your symbolic solution, I get an error saying "could not solve"... sympy 0.7.4.1.

Comment: I'm working in a canopy enviroment with sympy 0.7.6.1, maybe sympy learned something new. When I try to substitute the cos and sin with tan or exp I can't find a solution as well. Eventhough it should be the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I fix the missing parenthesis in your `numpy` example, I get a different result:

```
In [40]: b1,b2,c3
Out[40]: (0.21407625679722384, 2.8598524043642226, 0.4463029985826017)
```

And anyway your input points are not really good, since your variables are mixed up. Your function is defined in the order `b1,b2,c3`, yet the starting point corresponds to the symbolic solution of `c3,b1,b2`. Changing the order gives me

```
In [42]: b1,b2,c3
Out[42]: (2.9450733464142882, 0.07278767695320594, 1.1693849677611501)
```

Note that for a given `b1,b2` you'll also have a solution with `b1+2*k*pi,b2*2*l*pi` where `k,l` are integers.

I didn't put these numbers into your equations, but I'm pretty sure they solve them. The problem is, there are a bunch of solutions. As I said, your first two variables are periodic, and even then there can be a lot of other solutions with `c3`. If you use a bunch of different starting points for `fsolve`, you'll get a bunch of different solutions.

What's worse: your solution doesn't enforce the `0<c3<1` bound.

---

On the mathematics: due to the diversity of possible solutions, you might want to simplify the numerical problem on paper first.

For instance, the first equation is special, as it doesn't contain `c3`. You can relate `b1` to `b2`, albeit in a nonlinear way. For each `b1` you'll know that

```
b2=+-acos(0.0166-cos(b1))+2*k*pi
```

Which is already a constraint. Furthermore, adding Eq. 1 to Eq. 3 gives you

```
0 = 2*cos(b1)+ 5.4155*c3 - 4.3547-0.0166
```

in other words, `c3` is linearly dependent on `cos(b1)`. It might help if you introduce this into Eq. 2, getting a connection between functions of `b1` and `b2`. Essentially you have variables as `b1,b2(b1),c3(b1)`, with the single Eq. 2 to solve.

Another note: I'm guessing that the large number of equations comes from a lot of combinations for numerical factors in your equations. Isn't that right? If so, you might want to introduce some symbolic constants in the equations instead of the floating-point literals, and try to solve that. If you succeed, you don't have to solve a huge number of sets of nonlinear equations: you only have to solve one set, then substitute your various parameters.

Comment: I have troubles to find the missing parenthesis. I thought you mean the one in the end of return. It was missing in the code posted in this question (corrected already) but it was not missing in my script, so I still get the (0,0,0) solution

Comment: @Fips that's exactly what I meant. Are you sure your code is as above? If I start from `(0,0,0)`, it will give me another solution, so `(0,0,0)` doesn't seem to be a solution for me. Have you tried deleting the old variables, and then running the `numpy` solution? Or at least changing the variable names to avoid confusion with the symbolic ones.

Comment: Ok I see I had a problem with my printing command. I applied the function 'equations' a second time on the result... silly me. Thanks a lot for helping me here. Any idea how to set limits for variables? if I take bad input values I get angles of up to 2000 rad

Comment: @Fips, those angles are perfectly fine answers;) But if you prefer to stay in [0, 2pi], try `np.remainder(b1,2*np.pi)`. This should do the job. But don't forget that `np.remainder(b1,2*np.pi)+2*k*pi` is a perfectly valid solution for any integer `k`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Since I figured out how to use fsolve I tried to move on to a more advanced solution using optimize.minimize since scipy tutorial claims fsolve to be an old solver. I haven't fully unterstood it yet. Please feel free to share your knowledge in my second question here [link].
[link]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097739/which-variable-is-minimized-by-scipy-optimize-minimize-how-does-it-work?noredirect=1#comment54011330_33097739