# Which variable is minimized by scipy.optimize.minimize/How does it work?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

From scipy tutorial I don't really get how optimize.minimize works.
I want to minimize c3 in following set of equations:

```
0 = cos(b1)+ cos(b2)- 0.0166
0 = sin(b1)+ sin(b2)+ 0.3077*c3 - 0.6278
0 = cos(b1)- cos(b2)+ 5.4155*c3 - 4.3547
```

in intervals:

```
c3[0,1]
b1,b2[0,2*pi]
```

Here is my code:

```
def fun(x):
    return 4.9992-5.7233*x[0]-2*np.cos(x[2])-np.sin(x[2])-np.sin(x[1])
bnds = ((0,1),(0,2*np.pi),(0,2*np.pi))
i =  optimize.minimize(fun, (0.05,np.pi*0.5,np.pi), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds)
```

The Output is

```
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 6
    nfev: 30
     fun: -3.9601679766628886
       x: array([ 1.        ,  1.57079633,  0.46367497])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     jac: array([ -5.72330004e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   6.11841679e-05,
         0.00000000e+00])
     nit: 6
```

The result is the same in `L-BFGS-B` My understanding is that here c3 has become 1 which is still ok, but I wanted it to be lower. If I apply `fsolve` on the function it finds a root for c3=0.46.
btw why do I have to write x[0],x[1] and x[2] instead of c3,b1,b2 in the code?
Is there a more clever way using constrains e.g.?

Comment: `From scipy tutorial I don't really get how optimize.minimize works` can you tell us what exactly you don't understand? Is there some specific paragraph?

Comment: Firstly I don't get how to tell it to minimize c3, secondly I don't get the difference between constraints and boundaries. Mathematically speaking a boundary is a inequality constraint isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three transcendent equations for the 3 variables *b1*, *b2* and *c3*. What you need to do is to solve this 3 equations for your variables. As the equations are transcendent, it's possible that there is no solution, one solution or many solutions. Solving them with *Mathematica* gives:

```
In[30]:= eq1 = 0 == Cos[b1] + Cos[b2] - 0.0166;
eq2 = 0 == Sin[b1] + Sin[b2] + 0.3077*c3 - 0.6278;
eq3 = 0 == Cos[b1] - Cos[b2] + 5.4155*c3 - 4.3547;

In[42]:= Reduce[{eq1, eq2, eq3, b1 >= 0, b1 <= 2*Pi, b2 >= 0, 
  b2 <= 2*Pi, c3 >= 0, c3 <= 1}, {b1, b2, c3}]

During evaluation of In[42]:= Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

Out[42]= b1 == 0.214076 && b2 == 2.85985 && c3 == 0.446303
```

So there is in fact only one solution. Now you could also use `root` to find this solution of your system of equations numerically:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize

def f(x):
    b1, b2, c3 = x
    e1 = sp.cos(b1) + sp.cos(b2) - 0.0166
    e2 = sp.sin(b1) + sp.sin(b2) + 0.3077*c3 - 0.6278
    e3 = sp.cos(b1) - sp.cos(b2) + 5.4155*c3 - 4.3547
    return e1, e2, e3

res = sp.optimize.root(f, [0.5, 1.0, 1.0])
print('b1 = {}, b2 = {}, c3 = {}'.format(*res.x))
```

gives:

```
b1 = 0.214076256767, b2 = 2.85985240432, c3 = 0.446302998585
```

What you did with `minimize` is to minimize the sum of the three equations which is not equivalent to "minimize c3 in (the) set of equations".

`minimize` is not made for what you want. 'Minimize' does something like minimize find the x that minimizes `f(x) = x**2`. The answer would obviously be 'x=0'.

You have to write 'x[0]' because of the interface of 'minimize'. the function simply expects that you give the parameters you want to minimize in vector form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already solved the set of equations using fsolve. There are two solutions one qith c3 being something like 0.46 and another one with 1.16. Unfortunately fsolve only delivers one of them (depending on the estimate) and doesn't take boundaries. This set of equations represent a technical Problem with c3 being some Kind of cost function. c3=1 means maximum load on the engine, therefore c3>1 is impossible. If I use fsolve and end up with a solution higher than 1 eventhough a solution with c3<=1 exists, I'm screwed.

Comment: Do you think 'brute' would be suitable? unlike fsolve and root it has a range Parameter. I tried it before, but couldn't get it working for some reason, but I didn't try very hard.

Comment: You defined a function `func(x)` that is the sum of the 3 right-hand-sides of your equations. You then solved the equation `func(x) == 0`. This is not necessarily a solution of your *3* equations (you only solved one equation). 
Minimizing a function is something different than solving a set of equations. So I'm still not sure why you want to minimize anything to solve your problem.
I updated my answer with an actual solution of how to solve your system using Mathematica or *scipy*'s `root`.